# "Variable does not exist: $CustomMetadata" When referencing custom setting data in Apex

Tags: apex, customsetting

I created a List Custom Setting with fields that stores default date values. I want to use it in my Apex code (trigger handler), but I have getting the error "Variable does not exist: $CustomMetadata". I think I may be referencing it incorrectly.

```
if (relatedAccounts.get(t.WhatId).Class__c == 'A') {
     newTask.ActivityDate = $CustomMetadata.List.Class_Days_to_Add__c.A__c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$<custom setting api name>` syntax is not used in Apex (it's used in formulas, Visualforce, and perhaps a few other locations).

Instead, in Apex, we access them using the [Custom Settings methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) that Salesforce (Apex) provides.

It'll be something like `My_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance('Name of a specific custom setting record');`

That said, you should consider migrating List custom settings to use Custom Metadata Types instead (allows relationships, queries for __mdt objects don't count towards the SOQL query limit, they're available in unit tests (unlike custom settings, which you'd need to insert data for in tests), and they're able to be deployed)

Comment: +1 and, CMDT come with various get methods as well now, though LTA fields only bring back 255 characters (found that out the hard way, lol).

Comment: @Carly Nope. When you create a record for a list custom setting, "Name" is a required field. It's the value that you put into that "Name" field that you use with `getInstance()`